# rosmake my own teleop package and launch keyboard teleoperation -- no response

Tags: ros, turtlebot2, turtlebot, rosmake, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

It's my first time to use rosmake to build a new package. I met a problem and hope someone could help me:

Basically I followed the tutorial: h t t p://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDC89965A56E6A8D6 (for turtlebot 1, making a package is in part 3). I just want to use the original turtlebot_key.cpp (no modified) to build my own package and compile and run a keyboard teleoperation

Here are the steps I followed (on workstation, using turtlebot 2):

1. Create my own package "mytele":

   `roscreate-pkg mytele geometry_msgs rospy roscpp`
2. Add this line to the end of ~/.bashrc to let ROS know my new package:

   `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/mytele:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}`
3. Check if mytele can be recognized:

   `rospack find mytele`
4. Compile the package (no source file yet):

   `rosmake mytele mytele`
5. Copy turtlebot_key.cpp to the src folder
6. At the end of CMakeLists.txt, add:

   `rosbuild_add_executable(mytele_keyboard src/turtlebot_key.cpp)`
7. Compile the package again (the binary file "mytele_keyboard" is generated):

   `rosmake mytele mytele`
8. Create a launch file "mytele_keyboard.launch" and add the following lines to execute the node:

   `<
   launch>

   <node pkg=“mytele” type=“mytele_keyboard” name=“mytele_keyboard” output=“screen”>

   </node>

   </launch>`
9. Launch the launch file:

   `roslaunch mytele mytele_keyboard.launch`

With the turtlebot bringup having been initialized, I launched mytele and got no error message:

> ... logging to /home/kevinma/.ros/log/918f92d0-0555-11e3-8d5f-2cd05a67dbef/roslaunch-kevinma-TAICHI31-3963.log
>
> Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
>
> Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
>
> Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
>
> started roslaunch server h t t p://192.168.15.48:51907/
>
>
> SUMMARY
>
> ========
>
>
> PARAMETERS
>
>  * /rosdistro
>
>  * /rosversion
>
>
> NODES
>
>   /
>
>     mytele_keyboard (mytele/mytele_keyboard)
>
>
> ROS_MASTER_URI=h t t p://192.168.15.68:11311
>
>
> core service [/rosout] found
>
> process[mytele_keyboard-1]: started with pid [3972]
>
> Reading from keyboard
>
> ---------------------------
>
> Use arrow keys to move the turtlebot.

However, there was no response no matter what key I pressed (arrow or "i" or "j"). I tried to use

`rostopic echo /mobile_base/commands/velocity`

to look at the command and it seemed that no commands were send out.

Nevertheless, I tried to use the original teleop

`roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch`

and the turtlebot moved as expected and I could also see the velocity command changing.

I noticed that the original turtlebot_teleop is written in Python and mytele is built from the .cpp file, because the keys for operating the turtlebot are different, but I expect the c++ version should work too. In the tutorial video the turtlebot 1 in gazebo works well.

Are the steps I followed for turtlebot 1 only? Did I miss something when building the package? I am a beginner in compiling a ROS package. Please help and I would appreciate it.

Kevin Ma

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73285/rosmake-my-own-teleop-package-and-launch-keyboard-teleoperation----no-response/) by [kevinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/5755/kevinma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-08-16**:
Run `rqt_graph` (groovy) or `rxgraph` (fuerte) and `roswtf` and check if everything is connected correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must remap the mytele_keyboard/cmd_vel topic to the cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop, same way keyboard_teleop.launch does. Change your launch file to something like:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg=“mytele” type=“mytele_keyboard” name=“mytele_keyboard” output=“screen”>
    <remap from="mytele_keyboard/cmd_vel" to="cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

If it doesn't work, your teleop cmd_vel topic name must be something different, so type

```
rostopic list -v | grep Twist
```

to list all velocity command topics and change the remap accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kevinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/5755/kevinma/) on 2013-10-21**:
Although the question was asked a couple of months ago, I had a chance to look at it again recently. With better understanding of ROS this time, I redo the procedure using catkin. With the help of 'rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph', I found the problem mainly exists in remapping. Now I can successfully catkin_make my c++ file and teleop my turtlebot, with remap from = "cmd_vel". Nevertheless, if I use remap from = "mytele_node/cmd_vel", it does not successfully remap to "cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop" and the teleop node does not actually publish on the correct topic. I don't really know the cause of the difference since the official turtlebot teleop works fine with the keyboard_teleop.launch in which "remap from = turtlebot_teleop_keyboard/cmd_vel" is used. Maybe it is because Python is employed instead of C++ in this case.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-10-22**:
well... you must be careful with namespaces; thanks to rqt_graph you can easily check to what your are remapping your mytele_keyboard/cmd_vel topic and why it doesn't plug to cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop